# Aligning text in the centre of the screen between 2 buttons, one of which might not be visible

Tags: android, android-layout

This is difficult to explain, please bear with me.

I have a top menu bar in a design which has been given to me (it's a port).

The menu bar has two buttons, one on the left of the menu, one on the right, and a text title between the two buttons.

The text view is single line so that if the text is longer than the view, it shortens with an ellipsis at the end.  The text should be centred within the display width between the buttons.  The text is a title for the current content and it's OK that it might be shortened.  In practice, on most devices, only the odd letter or two gets chopped off.

If both buttons are visible, then it's very straightforward however, depending on where I am in the app, the right button might not be visible.  When it's not visible, I use View.GONE.  The problem is that the text now fills the remaining space, which is desired, but centres in that remaining space, not within the display width so that a short piece of text is offset to the right by the width of the first button.

Using View.INVISIBLE rather than View.GONE is not the answer as the text then centres correctly but doesn't use the available space to minimise the shortening of the text.

Here's the effect I'm trying to achieve:

Both buttons visible:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Left button |  Title text centred in display | Right button |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Right button hidden

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Left button |  Title text centred in display                |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Right button hidden with long text showing elipsis.  This is what I'm looking for.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Left button |  A really long piece of title text centred ...|
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's what I'm getting when i hide the right button, note that the text is not centred.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Left button |        Title text centred in this space       |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the layout I'm using currently.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/activitytitlegradient"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainMenuLeftButton" 
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"        
            android:src="@drawable/rr_boat_bow"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"        
            android:layout_weight="1"   
            android:layout_height="34dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

   <TextView  android:id="@+id/mainMenuTitle"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:background="#00ffffff"          
            android:text="Reference"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:textColor="#ffffff"     
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />


    <Button android:id="@+id/mainMenuRightButton" 
            android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
            android:text="Edit"     
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="3dip"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"                   
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

The first button is implemented as an ImageView to enable some other (non relevant) effects I'm doing elsewhere.  The text is hard coded only to help with laying out.  My code changes the text as needed.

I can do this with a custom view but I am sure there must be a way to do this with the standard framework.

Thank you for any clues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been dreaming about this problem - really! I've woken in the middle of the night thinking about how to fix this thing.  The code I posted below is fugly and it offends my eye every time I look at it.  The thought of writing a custom widget just to centre some text feels like taking a shotgun to a pimple on my nose.  So, I got stuck in again and I'm embarrased at how easy the solution turned out to be.

The trick is to use a relative layout, align the second button on the right and anchor the text centring to the parent.  The key tag is:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Here are the relevant snippets from the layout XML (I've removed the non-relevant tags to save space):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainMenuLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuLeftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dip"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/rr_boat_bow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuRightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainMenuLeftButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mainMenuRightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'll sleep well tonight.  No fugly code, no custom class.  UI in XML only - sweet!

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:background="@drawable/activitytitlegradient"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainMenuLeftButton" 
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"        
        android:src="@drawable/rr_boat_bow"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"        
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:layout_height="34dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView  android:id="@+id/mainMenuTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  // or fiexed like 400dp
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:background="#00ffffff"          
        android:text="Reference"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"     
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mainMenuLeftButton"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/mainMenuRightButton" 
        android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
        android:text="Edit"     
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

see if it works or you can add some rules like android:layout_xxxxx, it is more flexable with RelativeLayout.

EDIT: invisible & toRightOf as replied in comment

Comment: Thanks John, but RelativeLayout doesn't help. I've edited my OP in an attempt to clarify the effect I'm looking for.  Cheers

Comment: the RightButton should be "invisible" not gone.(sorry for neglect this). you can give a fixed value to the width of TextView. My thought is, put the left button left, put the right button right, and put the textView be right of the leftButton(...so I am wrong again in the response it should be androd:layout_toRightOf="@id/mainMenuLeftButton"), try give textView a fixed width? It should works

Comment: Thanks again John, but still not what I'm looking for.  I've added more clarification to my OP :)  The problem with using any fixed widths (anything other than wrap_content or fill_parent) is that it does not centre the text.  It works fine for short text but if the content is wider than the TextView, it fails.  Additionally, View.INVISIBLE is not useful because the width of the view is still used in laying out so long text (resulting in an elipsis) will not be centred in the display width, but will centre between the two buttons which works, but does not let me use the full available width

Comment: you need the third result(without right button textview use all the space)? then it should be "GONE", I misunderstood. try make a rule like maxWidth? I'm at home and without IDE... I will try later..

Comment: Hey John.  Thanks for the perseverence!  Yes, the third result is the key.  The text should center on the display, not within whatever space the textview has because the right button has gone.  I could do a maxwidth thing but only in a custom view, which I'm trying to avoid for maintainability (and because I'm on a fixed price contract ;))

Comment: I'm confused which result you want the second or the forth pic (short text without rightButton) It seems LinearLayout is better, RelativeLayout seems having no function as "use all space left"(sorry for my poor English)

Comment: Hi again.  I said it was difficult to explain ;)  The 3rd result is what I want.  Num 4 is what I'm getting.  I have a button on the left, text in the middle and a button on the right.  Text in the middle is too long for the space available so it shows with an elipsis at the end.  This is great.  Now, hide the right hand button using View.GONE so that it now takes no space in the layout.  The texview should now use that space (because it is available).  So before button has gone, text is "A really long piece..." and witohut the button, "A really long piece of text..." centred in the display

Comment: To further clarify.  The first 3 diagrams are all the same.  I've just shown short text and long text to illustrate how the layout should behave.  The 4th diagram is just to show what I get with every combintation I've tried.

Comment: :) I see. Only xml seems can't achieve this goal, maybe need some code to control the view. When the text is too long, use "GONE", else use "INVISIBLE", or when the text is short and without right button, give a maxwidth to the textView(the maxwidth depends on the device)...

Comment: OK, thanks.  Looks like I'll have to code up a custom view.  I'll post the result back when I've got it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I ended up writing a static method to manipulate the layout.  It would be better as a custom class which extends the layout but I'm pushed for time and this was the quickest solution.  If I claw some time back, I will write a custom class or possibly, switch to using an ActionBar.

Anyway, if it helps anyone else, here's how I solved it:

```
public static void hideMainMenuRightButton(Context _context, RelativeLayout mainMenu) {

    // remove the right button from the view
    mainMenu.findViewById(R.id.mainMenuRightButton).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // get the width of the title text
    final Paint p = new Paint();
    final TextView tvTitle = (TextView) mainMenu.findViewById(R.id.mainMenuTitle);
    // scale the width in pixels according to density
    final float densityMultiplier = _context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final float scaledPx = tvTitle.getTextSize() * densityMultiplier;
    p.setTextSize(scaledPx);
    // measure the width
    int textWidth = (int) p.measureText(tvTitle.getText().toString());

    // get the width of the textview (screen width minus left button width)
    final int displayWidth = ((WindowManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int leftButtonWidth = ((ImageView) mainMenu.findViewById(R.id.mainMenuLeftButton)).getMeasuredWidth();
    int textViewWidth = displayWidth - leftButtonWidth;

    if (textWidth==0 || leftButtonWidth==0){return;}

    // set the left padding of the textview to centre its text in the display width
    tvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    if (textWidth < textViewWidth) {
        tvTitle.setPadding((textViewWidth - textWidth) / 2, 0, 0, 0);
    } else { // not enough room for the text to centre
        tvTitle.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

    }
}
```